# what's a RESTful way to save draft posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autosave

I have a posts controller on a small test website I'm making. I want to have a 'save draft'/combo-auto-save function to the site, as the site will have long posts that users may want to leave and come back to finish. However, I've never built an autosave/save function into a Rails app before (or any app). What is a good, RESTful way to do so?

Here is my current controller action:

posts_controller.rb

```
 def create

 @post = params[:post]
 if @post.save
     flash.now[:success] = "Post created!"
 else 
     render_errors_now(@post) 
 end
     respond_to do |format|
           format.html {redirect_to Discussion.find(session[:discussion_id])}
           format.js
     end
 end
```

As you can see, users post remotely.

Here is the current post.rb model:

```
 attr_accessible :content, :title
 validates :title, :presence => true 
 validate :title_character_length

 validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 10000 }
 validates :user_id, :presence => true
 validates :discussion_id, :presence => true
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :discussion
 default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at ASC'

 def title_character_length
    #some code that checks length
 end
```

I would need to accomplish the following things from this code..

1. Auto-save periodically (1 min intervals, perhaps)
2. Give option to save draft
3. Choose which validations to run: I would want to allow users to, for example, save a draft with a title that exceeds the allowed length, while not allowing them to actually post  a post with that title.

I also am curious what is a good Rails practice for saving drafts: should I add an attribute "draft" to the post model? Or create a draft posts model?

OK please comment if I need to provide more info. I'm interested to hear people's input! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-save:

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('form[data-remote]').submit();
  }, 1000*60); // 1000ms * 60s = 1m
});
```

You'll then need to have an `update.js.erb` to handle the messages ("Saved", for example).

For drafts, I would make a separate model, `PostDraft`. The auto-save will be saving the `PostDraft` object, and then once they click "Publish" or whatever, it will create a new `Post` and delete the `PostDraft`. This method will also allow the user to have titles longer than the limit, just by not putting that validation on the PostDraft model. This would be a lot more difficult if you did it all from within the `Post` model with a "draft" boolean.

Comment: An extra periodic "kill stale old PostDraft instances" step would be a nice addition, otherwise you'll end up with a lot of abandoned PostDrafts that no one cares about anymore.

Comment: thanks to both of you! I am wondering, would I initialize the variable for the form (let's say it's @post) as a Post.new or a PostDraft.new? Which controller action (post create, postdraft create, update..?) will the javascript submit the form to?

Comment: Keep PostDraft completely separate from Post. `@draft = PostDraft.new`, `form_for @draft`, PostDraftsController#update, etc. If there is any code that Post and PostDraft share, you can either include it as a module, OR you can do something like `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base`, `class Published < Post`, `class Draft < Post`. That makes more sense but it's a little more complex.

Comment: OK, that's illuminating. But, what would you do to allow a post to submit to Post controller (if it's a PostDraft) when they click "post" for final submission?

Comment: Hey Bricker - out of interest, i'm trying also an implementation of a boolean field in the Post Controller (I think this is slicker). How would one have a boolean field "draft" be set to "true" for auto-save (the javascript you wrote) submission, but not post submission?

Comment: Make it default for PostDraft when you create the migration: `t.boolean :autosave, :default => 1`. Opposite for Post. And then watch the checkbox so that when it's changed `$('.post_draft_auto_save').change(...)`, auto save or not accordingly. Post a separate question if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: hey, thanks that makes sense. I have another question that I could really use your help on, if you could spare the time, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718971/when-autosaving-how-do-i-make-submissions-update-a-draft-rather-than-create-a-ne

Comment: at that question there i ask: how can I change the code to submit to the "create" action for the first autosave and then to the "update" action thereafter?